# python unable to extract zip file uploaded to aws s3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3

```
medias = ['https://baby-staging-bucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/asset/0002.jpg', 
        'https://baby-staging-bucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/asset/2.png', 
        'https://baby-staging-bucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/asset/02.png'
    ]
for i in medias:
    file_name = i.split("/")[-1]
    urllib.urlretrieve (i, "media/"+file_name)

# writing files to a zipfile
local_os_path = f'media/{title}.zip'
with ZipFile(local_os_path, 'w') as zip:
    # writing each file one by one
    for file in medias:
        file_name = file.split("/")[-1]
        zip.write("media/"+file_name)
        os.remove("media/"+file_name)
    
    s3 = session.resource('s3')
    storage_path = f'asset/nfts/zip/{title}.zip'
    s3.meta.client.upload_file(Filename=local_os_path, Bucket=AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME, Key=storage_path)
    # os.remove(local_os_path)
    DesignerProduct.objects.filter(id=instance.id).update(
        zip_file_path=S3_BUCKET_URL + storage_path, 
    )
```

I am using this code to create zip file and saving to w3 bucket.
Fitst i am downloading to localsystem then zipping all files and saving zip file to s3 bucket
In my local system i am able to extract zip file but when i download from s3 bucket i am not able to extract it.

```
https://baby-staging-bucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/asset/nfts/zip/ant.zip
```

This is my path of s3 where zip file uploaded .
what can be the reason please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the upload after the `with` block.

You are uploading your zipfile before the archive is closed.
See [ZipFile.close()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.close):

> Close the archive file. You must call close() before exiting your program or essential records will not be written.

`close` is automatically called by the `with` statement.

You open your local file after the program exits - which means after the zipfile is closed - so your local version is not corrupted.